# Solid angle created from irregular polygon (over a sphere)

Tags: polygons, solid-angle

[image]

[image]

I have an $n$-polygon on a sphere ($n\geqslant3$). In this example the vertices are $C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K$. Which solid angle alpha generate this polygon respect origin of the sphere? For $C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K$ are know coordinate Cartesian or polar.

I am searching for a "closed solution" without integrals, and when is the solid angle generated from polygon $KJIHGFEDC$ being $β=4π-α$?

Comment: Do you have co-ordinates for the points?

Comment: Yes, I apologize for my bad English

Comment: You might want to read up on spherical excess. See, for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Area_and_spherical_excess

Comment: The precise answer depends on whether (i) the triangle sides are great circle arcs ''on'' the sphere or (ii) the triangle sides are straight (Cartesian) lines that cut through the sphere.